# One word to describe a boy who immediately jumps to do what he is told

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a book and need help finding a word to describe a boy who immediately jumps to do what he is told. This is the sentence it will be used in ->

> "Ulric bring me a glass of water," Yohann says, in a raucous tone, as he turns back to the window seeming to forget about the ________ boy who scrambles to follow his grandfathers request.

I might need to rephrase the sentence...

Comment: You need to decide ***why*** he does so, is he *eager*, *harassed*, *obsequious*, *obedient*...?

Comment: Also include information on how the word will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some off the top of my head, with varying degrees of negative and positive connotations:

**Accommodating**

**Obedient**

**Eager-to-please**

**Helpful**

**Hospitable**

**Agreeable**

**Dutiful**

**Subservient**

**Deferential**

**Devoted**

**Attentive**

**Cooperative**

**Steadfast**

**Loyal**

**Faithful**

Comment: Thanks everyone! The suggestions and comments were very helpful.